# How to rollback transaction if row changed?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am using `Postgres 9.3`.

When I update row in a table my flow looks like this:

1. Fetch old row (ex. `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = 1`)
2. Validate new data in scope of old data (old row fetched in point 1) - this is done by my app outside of postgres.
3. Update row with new data (ex. `UPDATE tbl SET .... WHERE id = 1`)

The problem is that `old` data may change during point 2 so validation, even if passed may be `outdated` during point 3 (updating row). I know I could perform update like this `UPDATE .... WHERE id = 1 AND column1='oldValue'` to ensure certain fields didn't change, however my validation (also comparising new and old values) is very complex and I can't "write" it in SQL UPDATE statement.

So I thought about something like this:

1. `BEGIN`
2. `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = 1`
3. Perform validation on my side
4. `UPDATE SET=... WHERE id = 1`
5. `COMMIT`

And I would like to `COMMIT` fail if row with id = 1 changed during transaction execution. Is it possible to use transaction like this? If not what is other solution?

Comment: Note that the accepted answer does not "rollback transaction if row changed", rather it prevents the row to change (until commit). To test if a row has changed between 2 points in time you can simply put it into a record variable and perform a row-wise comparison later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why you are not updating directly with additional predicates in the where clause, but if that is not possible you can select for update as in:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE
```

This will lock the selected row and prevent updates of it while you do your validation.

Answer (score 2):

You could put a lock on the table while you do the validation.

```
BEGIN WORK;
LOCK TABLE tbl IN exclusive mode;
select * from tbl where id = 1;
--Do your validation 
update tbl set .. where id = 1;
COMMIT WORK;
```